# Error upgrading to WSL 2 : There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper

Tags: windows, powershell, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

There was no problem with WSL1. I wanted to upgrade to WSL 2.

Command line fails when I try to upgrade to wsl2. I tried to remove Ubuntu and reinstall it, no difference.

Virtual Machine Platform is active.

Windows build number: 19041.208

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

The output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
```

I tried to remove the ubuntu and run the following command first:

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

after installing ubuntu again it keeps stuck on:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
```

when I CTRL+C and relaunch it again it gives me this error:

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8000000d An illegal state change was requested.
```

I don't know what to do now. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Fixed it .. uninstalled Windows Subsystem for Linux and Virtual Hypervisor Platform restart then reinstall them then restart .. it worked after

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the original error from the post

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800706d9
Error: 0x800706d9 There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
```

What ended up being the issue for me was the Host Network Service was not running. I set it to run automatically and started it up. I was then able to launch Ubuntu and set it as the default in WSL 2.

Comment: Thanks. Most hits for 'WSL' and 'Error: 0x800706d9' suggest that it is a problem with the configuration of Hyper-V virtual networking and/or the Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service. 
That might well be true, but for me enabling 'Host Network Service' was the last link that got WSL2 working again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes shows this because wsl 2 is already installed and set to version 2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and uninstall/ install **Windows Subsystem Linux Update** works well.

Step 1:
Add or remove programs

Search "Linux"

Uninstall

[image]

Step 2:

[install](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/wsl/install) WSL again

Then `wsl -l` works again.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue is being by caused ICS being disabled. ICS is used by the Host Network Service (HNS) to create a virtual network which WSL 2 relies on for NAT, DNS, DHCP, and host connection sharing.

To solve the issue, Go to services, then:

1. Restart Host Network Service
2. Restart LxssManager

- LSSXManager manages the Windows Subsystem for Linux kernel mode driver (lxss.sys). The kernel mode driver provides the core functionality needed to translate Linux system calls to Windows system calls.

You can read more from microsoft's troubleshooting guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).